# Imagick - no decode delegate for this image format

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, imagemagick, imagick

I am trying to convert PNGs to GIF using ImageMagick on my Ubuntu server. I used a PHP code to generate it however when I ran it, I received..

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format

Then I used: `convert -list configure`, on the libs, I didn't see either gif or png. So I researched a bit more, and found that I should remove and re-install Imagick..

So I tried `sudo apt-get remove imagemagick`, and then..

`sudo apt-get install libperl-dev gcc libjpeg-dev libbz2-dev libtiff4-dev libwmf-dev libz-dev libpng12-dev libx11-dev libxt-dev libxext-dev libxml2-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms1-dev libexif-dev perl libjasper-dev libltdl3-dev graphviz pkg-config`

After it completed installing, I used `wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0.tar.gz` and got the latest version.

But then, I got totally lost. I uncompressed it using `tar -xzf ImageMagick-x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0.tar.gz`. I was expecting to find `./configure` in here, but I couldn't.

What am I missing or doing wrong? Am I completely out of track?

Comment: i'm facing the same issue so i 'm moving the temporary uploaded file to another location and giving it it's original name and extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You downloaded iOS binaries instead of sources. You need sources if you want to compile them by hand:

http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick-6.9.3-0.tar.gz

With this file you will be able to compile ImageMagick with whatever image formats you want.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php

Edit: Step-by-step instructions

```
wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick-6.9.3-0.tar.gz
tar xvzf ImageMagick-6.9.3-0.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick-6.9.3-0
./configure
```

Make sure that the output of the previous command shows this:

```
PNG               --with-png=yes        yes
```

And then:

```
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

Comment: I am not so good with terminal commands when I am ssh'd in the local machine. Can you please add the necessary commands to write in your answer? Because I have been trying different stuff but got quiet lost. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @senty I added more detailed instructions

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just checked, it outputs `PNG               --with-png=yes  yes` when I use `./configure`. But still the same error `no decode delegate for this image format`. What am I doing wrong? Please note that I did everything as you showed. I think PNG is there, but GIF is not. What is the way of adding it?

Comment: Update: I also ran `identify -list format`. I can see `PNG* rw-   Portable Network Graphics (libpng 1.2.50)` *AND* `GIF* rw+   CompuServe graphics interchange format` but still receiving the same error, no decode delegate. What do you think can be the problem?

Comment: Which bit do you need to see? The libs bit is `LIBS -ljbig  -ltiff -lfreetype   -ljpeg   -lpng12       -lfontconfig -lfreetype    -lwmflite  -lXext -lXt   -lSM -lICE -lX11  -llzma   -lbz2     -lxml2    -lz    -lm -lgomp`. Please let me know if you need to see any other bit because it's quiet long. Thnx

Comment: @senty The 'delegates' part.

Comment: 'delegates' : `DELEGATES bzlib mpeg fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lzma png ps tiff wmf x xml zlib`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99948/discussion-between-awons-and-senty).